# How to get available scroll x amount

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to figure the amount available to scroll right. If a user has a smaller screen, the content that is appended will look cut off and I would like to just scroll for them in a smoother fashion. I have used

```
scrollTo(99999, y);
```

but that just jumps. I think my best bet would be something along the lines of:

```
var inter = setInterval(function(){
  if(available_amount_x > 0){
    scrollBy(10, 0);
  }else{
    clearInterval(inter);
  }
}, 100);
```

In short, how do I get available_amount_x

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what do you exactly want but gave an answer, hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to scroll at the right end

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($.browser.safari) bodyelem = $("body");
    else bodyelem = $("html,body");

    setTimeout(function(){
        $(bodyelem).animate({'scrollLeft': $(window).width()},'slow');
    }, 1000);
});
```

This will scroll the document at the rightmost after 1 second of document load. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gk6NJ/1/).